# World line interpretation

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames

Suppose I want to draw the coordinate axes of an observer 'P' in the space time diagram of 'O'. Also observer 'P' is moving with velocity 'v'.

In order to draw time axis of observer 'P', I can see physically that it denotes the locus of origin of spacial coordinates of 'P'. So the tangent of the angle made by the time axis of 'P' with the time axis of 'O' should be equal to |v|. Is there a physical way to see that position axis of 'P' will also make the same angle with the position axis of 'O'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, suppose your observers meet at an event M.
Construct the unit hyperbola in the future light cone of M.
Given an inertial worldline through M, locate the intersection event (call it Q) with the unit hyperbola. The **tangent at Q** is Minkowski-orthogonal to that worldline [thought of as a radial direction]---**these events are all simultaneous with Q according to that worldline**. Now, draw the parallel to that tangent through event M... these events are all simultaneous with M according to that worldline....i.e., the instantaneous "position axis" of that observer at event M.

By the properties of the unit hyperbola (which encodes the Lorentz Transformation), you can see that the "angle" between the observer worldlines is equal to the "angle" between their position axes in this diagram.
(Of course, we are assuming a spacetime diagram where the speed of light is drawn at 45 degrees.)

Play around with my simulation (where time runs to the right)
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/awgqxtkqcc

[image]

By the way, this "tangent is perpendicular to radius" construction is used by Minkowski in his "Space and Time" paper. (See my related reply at [Derivation of Lorentz boosts](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/369281/derivation-of-lorentz-boosts/369321) ).

If that isn't physical enough, I can update this answer with a radar construction.